# Spring integration persistent message store

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

How I tell spring integration to persist messages within the flow and to recover when application is shut down?

I have spring integration flow like this:

```
IntegrationFlows
            .from(ftpInboundAdapter) { c -> c.poller(Pollers.fixedRate(1000).maxMessagesPerPoll(1)) }
            .transform<File, JobLaunchRequest> { toAJobRequest(it, aJob) }
            .handle(JobLaunchingGateway(jobLauncher))
            .transform<JobExecution, JobLaunchRequest> { toBJobRequest(bJob) }
            .handle(JobLaunchingGateway(jobLauncher))
            .handle { _ -> }
            .get()
```

I have tried to add

```
    @Bean
    fun jdbcChannelMessageStore(dataSource: DataSource): JdbcChannelMessageStore? {
        val jdbcChannelMessageStore = JdbcChannelMessageStore(dataSource)
        jdbcChannelMessageStore.setChannelMessageStoreQueryProvider(H2ChannelMessageStoreQueryProvider())
        return jdbcChannelMessageStore
    }
```

without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea about a JDBC `MessageStore` is correct, only the problem that you don't show how you use that `jdbcChannelMessageStore` bean.

According to [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/system-management.html#message-store) you need to have a `QueueChannel` with this `MessageStore` injected, but your flow comes fully without any channel customization.

To make a persistent channel in your flow, you need to have something like this:

```
.channel { c -> c.queue(jdbcChannelMessageStore, "persistentGroup") }
```

(you need to inject a `jdbcChannelMessageStore` bean somehow in your flow).

This way messages are going to be stored in the Data Based in the `INT_CHANNEL_MESSAGE` table. They will survive a crash over there.

Also you need to keep in mind that `QueueChannel` is not *subscribable*, it has to be *polled*. Therefore an endpoint just after this channel definition in the flow, has to be configured with the `poller`. For example:

```
  .channel { c -> c.queue(jdbcChannelMessageStore, "persistentGroup") }
  .handle(JobLaunchingGateway(jobLauncher), e -> e.poller(p -> p.fixedDelay(1000)))
```

All the answers are present in the docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/dsl.html#java-dsl-pollers

BTW, we have a dedicated project to make Kotlin experience easier: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-extensions/tree/master/spring-integration-kotlin-dsl

Comment: The reason i did not show how I use the jdbcChannelMessageStore is that i did not use it -and that was the problem. I thought that if I explicitly define the store like that, it will be injected somewhere and persistent channel will be used as default. I now understand it is nonsense.